# Does sheaf of smooth functions recover the smooth structure?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, sheaf-theory

Given a smooth manifold $M$, one can easily define its sheaf of smooth functions. I hope to arrive the following statement:

> Sheaves are *just* good devices that keep track of extra structures other than its topology,

which leads to my **question**:

> Can we recover the smooth manifold $M$ from its underlying topological space and its sheaf of smooth functions?

Please let me know if I should be clearer!

Comment: The answer should be yes because manifolds are equivalently defined as locally ringed spaces that are locally isomorphic to open subsets of euclidean space with the usual structure sheaf. Thus if you know $(M, O_M)$ you should find charts as open subsets $U$ with isomorphisms $(U, O_{M\mid U}) \to (\mathbb R^n, O_{\mathbb R^n})$. I don't have a reference and don't have time to write the details though

Comment: This reduced my problem to local! However, given a smooth structure on $R^n$, does (topological($R^n$), $O_{R^n}$) recover it?

Comment: What I meant was that your isomorphisms $(U,O_U)\to (\mathbb R^n, O_\mathbb R^n)$ gave you the charts for $M$ : you recovered your atlas ! The question of whether conversely a locally euclidean sheaf of smooth functions gives you a manifold is another one, but I think it is true

Comment: Sorry, I don't see why you have the isomorphisms $(U,O|_U) \to (\mathbb{R}^n,O_{\mathbb{R}^n})$

Comment: Well you look at all locally ringed space maps and some of them are isomorphisms

Comment: The underlying topological space only remembers the topological information of some domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and the sheaf knows nothing about $\mathbb{R}^n$ I would say.